# Windows store app automating testing, run and detect when the application is stopped (suspended) c++

Tags: c++, testing, windows-store-apps

Im using this guide "automating the testing of windows 8 apps" to test my windows store app

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx

Unfortunaltely Ive run into a problem, I need to know when my app closes (crashes) or when it goes into suspended mode, to log that info, and I want the launcher to be able to know the application has stopped , unfortunately *iApplicationActionManager*,  does not have that method. And *IPackageDebugSettings* which is used to change the application *suspend* and *resume* states does not have a readable current state property (afaik)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could [query the event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if your package name has showed up.

Comment: Thanks for that idea It made me look this from a different angle and I found this article thanks to that. I could log a crash and check if the log has been modified using by using a proxy with the FileSystemWatcher class. Im going to try that. http://jaysonsblog.azurewebsites.net/post/Executing-External-Process-from-Windows-8-Metro-Application-Using-Native-Proxy